# functionality of datafilter in Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have not been able to get a clear idea of the purpose of datafilter in jquery.

while searching I found the following
datafilter: A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest. This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response.

Can anyone give me a clear idea? Am new to jquery and Ajax.

Answer (score 4):

An example of WHAT it could be for could be a custom data compression implementation.
Say you're returning xml or json and you want to compress is.  You could potentially add a dataFilter that decompresses the raw data and returns it.

Note that the dataFilter runs PRIOR to the parser.  So as long as you return valid json, xml, etc the parser will come along and pass on the response in the correct type.

ex:

```
$.ajaxSetup({dataFilter:decompressRaw}); //global decompression for all calls from the page

function decompressRaw(data, dataType){
     return someDecompressionFunction(data);
}
```